# Considerations about optimizing singlepage mobile web apps by inlining all js and css

Tags: performance, html, web-applications, jquery-mobile, inline

I am creating a mobile singlepage web app using jquery mobile. The webapp includes a number of javascript files and a number of css files. I have written a deploy script that concatenates and minifies js and css files, and now I am wondering whether I should inline the concatenated js and css directly in the HTML file - please note that I am talking about a singlepage app here (I know that this would be a bad idea in a traditional web 1.0 app with dynamically generated HTML). I am also using appcache/manifest file to cache the singlepage app so that subsequent access to the web app will be served from the cache, so it is the initial load time that is my primary concern.

When I inline everything (jquery, jquery mobile etc.), my 7kb HTML file increases to 350kb (100kb zipped) but now everything can be loaded in a single request.

But am I missing some other benefits such as parallel downloading of js files - and would it therefore be better to not inline the css and js, but instead just concatenate all js and css to a single js file and a single css file and then fetch each of them in separate requests?

Are there any limits regarding file size that I should be aware of? Maybe caching in network routers works better with smaller file sizes or whatever?

So my question boils down to whether it is a good idea to inline *everything* when making singlepage mobile web apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to how much should be concatenated and how much should be inlined varies depending on a number of conditions. The final answer is you should do A/B testing and find what works best for you. From what you describe I recommend you definitely NOT inline 350K of CSS & JS. If you do this then any change to the HTML or JS or CSS requires downloading the entire payload. Instead, compartmentalize those changes and forced updates by keeping HTML, JS, & CSS as separate requests. You could do [dynamic](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/dynamic-inlining.php) | [inlining](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2011/03/28/storager-case-study-bing-google/) to make the first response fast but leverage (app or localStorage) cache for subsequent requests, but that's going to get complicated when coupled with app cache (because the HTML doc is saved to app cache). Otherwise, just keep them separate, save each resource to app cache, and update individual resources as needed.

Comment: ok thanks. But how important is it generally speaking to reduce the number of requests for mobile browser? Would you not concatenate any js files to minimize the payload? Is there a rule of thumb for how large blocks js and css one should make by concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend inlining everything into the html if your webapp could be accessed from different urls with different querystring. 
Example :

- http://webapp.com/?fb_token=fdsf
- http://webapp.com/?referer=bla
- http://webapp.com/?tracker=toto

Each of those will add a master copy in the appcache (you can veryfy it by looking at chrome://appcache-internals/ in chrome). You then risk to reach the quota limit for appcache in term of cache. Furthermore on appcache update, the browser goes through its appcache entry list and ask a fresh copy of it. 
A good compromise that i am following for mobile device & appcache , is to keep the html tiny  and then have one big css (containing base 64 inlined images) and one js file.

FYI, there is currently a quota limit on the size on the sum of all your listed resources in appcache in the order from 5MB to 25MB (25 being the new iOS6 limit)

-seb